# SQLConnection.Open() with .sdf database; throwing exception

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to C#, I need to connect to a .sdf database, I am using the following connection but keep getting an exception and I don't know why

```
        bool stat = true;
        string connectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|'\'CarsDB.sdf;Initial  Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=true;";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            textBox2.Text = "true";

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            stat = false;
            textBox2.Text = "false";
        }
```

The exception is:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).

Comment: You're working with a SQL CE database, so you should be using eg. `SqlCeConnection`, not `SqlConnection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is code:

```
bool stat
        string connectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|'\'CarsDB.sdf;Initial  Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=true;";
try
{
     conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString );
     conn.Open();
        textBox2.Text = "true";  

   /*  SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers ([Customer ID], [Company Name]) Values('NWIND', 'Northwind Traders')";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();*/

}
 catch (System.Exception)
    {
        stat = false;
        textBox2.Text = "false";
    }
```